# Overriding a conditional variable in UnrealScript with a child class in Deus Ex?

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I'm actually using the original Deus Ex game from the year 2000. I created a child class of "DeusEx.Flare" and called it "rflare" and saved it to my own package. I have successfully compiled it, and it works, but not the way I intended. I want to override the function "LifeSpan = 30" and give it "LifeSpan = 120". The problem is the documentation. There practically is none. And the documentation I can find generally is too confusing and does not give good enough examples for what I'm tryng to do. here is the code. I know I'm supposed to be using the "super" expression but I have exhausted all the ways I know how to use it. I simply cannot get it to work. However, I can get it to work if I dont' mind throwing both the normal flare (which goes out in 30 seconds) and my own flare, which only drops to the ground without a sound but will in fact last 120 seconds. So my code would end up throwing 2 flares. 1 normal flare that goes out in 30 sec. and the other that does last 120 but does not get thrown like the normal flare does.

here is the code from DeusEx.Flare script that I'm trying to change.

```
function LightFlare()
{
local Vector X, Y, Z, dropVect;
local Pawn P;

if (gen == None)
 {  
    LifeSpan = 30;
 }
}
```

My first attempt was to copy this and change it in my own package. It worked but again, it shot 2 flares, 1 normal and 1 that sorta worked. I want to do only one. So here is my attempt at correcting the code.

```
function LightFlare()
{
Super(Flare).LightFlare();

if (gen == None)
    {
        LifeSpan = 120;
    }
}
```

All this does is spawn the normal flare, with no difference in the time it lasts. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest copying the LightFlare function in it's entirety from the parent class and not calling super. You don't want the original function to run, as that will mess with the lifetime variable.

For instance:

```
    class RFlare extends Flare;

    function LightFlare()
    {
       local Vector X, Y, Z, dropVect;
       local Pawn P;

       // Original function here, change lifetime when specified.

       if (gen == None)
       {  
          LifeSpan = 120;
       }
    }

    defaultproperties
    {
    }
```